# How can I assign multiple related objects to an object in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following two models

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I have an object `@post` and an array of comments `@comments`. How can I assign all the comment objects to post in a single line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@post.comments = @comments
```

should do what you're asking. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
@post.update_attributes(:comments => @comments)
```

OR

```
@post.comments = @comments ; @post.save
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly do you mean, but maybe this will help:

```
@post.comments << @comments
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is

```
@post.comments = @comments
```

However you may want to examine carefully how exactly you are creating your comments. It is more likely that comments will need to be created one at a time and in that case you can simply do the following

```
@post.comments.create!(:body => "foo")
```

This will add a new comment to your Post